# Box function signal filtering in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, signal-processing

I am trying to produce a box function filter of a signal in python. I expected to find this functionality in scipy.signal, but I can't find any solutions. What I am trying to do is this.

I have 2 signals that look like this:
[image]

I have the peaks plotted for both of the signals, as you can see. I am trying to create a box function filter so that I can get a result like this:

[image]

Here, the two signals are filtered so that that peaks are centered in a constant variable window, lets say 5.

You can also see that signals are normalized so that all maxima are 1 and all minima are 0. Is there any prebuilt solution for this?

#### EDIT

I'm getting closer to figuring it out, but I keep having trouble. Here is my code so far:

```
raw_signal = [0.04583763329719659,
 0.04805497846973594,
 0.04829505014640745,
 0.05887341212655883,
 0.05002700454497244,
 0.03658229798020329,
 0.03785355329455342,
 0.041801968109211884,
 0.02233076920674648,
 0.058624423036235385,
 0.04285942959540989,
 0.05198790422582533,
 0.07342396020248998,
 0.05624460427497979,
 0.053187046069069766,
 0.05705776529794093,
 0.055122999401646666,
 0.03843830454570707,
 0.05200852137932088,
 0.057458145238342695,
 0.04733597124868538,
 0.07260882812261116,
 0.05444879316200968,
 0.06107602057454642,
 0.05144282440596726,
 0.03842927653749939,
 0.062157345746527426,
 0.049414162276661955,
 0.06244672513275873,
 0.026325066210119985,
 0.049222807501791976,
 0.048303400035365485,
 0.033270250060013495,
 0.06265669035201427,
 0.0464532491605496,
 0.04716381918115076,
 0.05001360514143016,
 0.04871139499300625,
 0.03684319926833268,
 0.06930899362487253,
 0.04683942206611391,
 0.053229054537951015,
 0.05761049069405999,
 0.06470925254689064,
 0.0671662015520269,
 0.04771008352690842,
 0.06945096065464895,
 0.016286753452732228,
 0.05102230607008096,
 0.01769710761436727,
 0.06242152849154081,
 0.019350205184309743,
 0.03038432296307292,
 0.0609150647505885,
 0.05489945724548306,
 0.05819547914143186,
 0.026275048367097043,
 0.015321600585593842,
 0.05769180825154763,
 0.04853383834415581,
 0.04002726600447204,
 0.03246579690312501,
 0.05159124229976442,
 0.04558678156172391,
 0.04065268985868897,
 0.05376688459364232,
 0.03983559690823313,
 0.02996508228534367,
 0.024953327010734938,
 0.05553271730605047,
 0.04297505620343145,
 0.05980710957373958,
 0.04593995363393333,
 0.05778656013717409,
 0.040827999691828154,
 0.019963644081144594,
 0.051858118604286574,
 0.06540824360854458,
 0.05649360937240999,
 0.04654800250136759,
 0.05910070285608526,
 0.058185853049508296,
 0.05541932878259104,
 0.04814119565708097,
 0.015593319767504,
 0.0365044306818163,
 0.06034806101524737,
 0.037100095869391225,
 0.054988950068945996,
 0.02537936052249279,
 0.031081240376806818,
 0.06072348878660705,
 0.011991354040219449,
 0.044582271584658884,
 0.060200185907888226,
 0.040700219324207865,
 0.04851865196542349,
 0.056848127496778034,
 0.03311677974124905,
 0.05129374585521873]
```

```
def make_chunks(lst, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from lst."""
    chunks = []
    for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
        chunks.append(lst[i:i + n])
    
    return chunks


def get_local_max_min(windowed_chunks):

    max_coords = []
    min_coords = []
    original_idx = 0

    for i in windowed_chunks:
        local_maxima = max(i)
        local_minima = min(i)
        local_max_idx = i.index(local_maxima) + original_idx
        local_min_idx = i.index(local_minima) + original_idx
        local_max_coords = [local_max_idx, local_maxima]
        local_min_coords = [local_min_idx, local_minima]
        max_coords.append(local_max_coords)
        min_coords.append(local_min_coords)
        original_idx += window

    return max_coords, min_coords
    

def join_and_sort_coords(max_coords, min_coords):
    
    coord_lst = max_coords + min_coords
    coord_lst = sorted(coord_lst, key=lambda x: x[0])
    
    return coord_lst
    

def box_filter(coord_list, box_filter_span):
    
    box_filter_list = []
    for i in coord_list:
        mod_val = ([i[1]]*box_filter_span)
        box_filter_list.append(mod_val)
        
    box_filter_list = [item for sublist in box_filter_list for item in sublist]
        
    return box_filter_list
    

def plot_signals(raw_signal, max_coords, min_coords, box_filter_list):
    
    plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
#     plt.plot(raw_signal)
    plt.plot(box_filter_list)
    for x,y in max_coords:
        plt.plot(x,y, color='red', marker = 'o')
    for x,y in min_coords:
        plt.plot(x,y, color='green', marker = 'o')


window = 10
box_filter_span = 5
windowed_chunks = make_chunks(raw_signal, window)
max_coords, min_coords = get_local_max_min(windowed_chunks)
coord_list = join_and_sort_coords(max_coords, min_coords)
box_filter_list = box_filter(coord_list, box_filter_span)
plot_signals(raw_signal, max_coords, min_coords, box_filter_list)
```

Which produces this:

[image]

This is wrong because it should alternate max-min-max-min and so on, like in the second plot. You can see my plot breaking at the 3rd minima.

Comment: There is such a thing as a ["box filter"](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#gad533230ebf2d42509547d514f7d3fbc3), but I don't think that's what you are after. The second plot is difficult to see. What do you mean to show there? Could the "ppg" and "inverse green" signals be processed independently, or is the idea that they are used together somehow to produce the result?

Comment: @PascalGetreuer thanks for your reply. I made some edits and provided my code so far. Hopefully this helps clarify. The 2 signals can be processed independently. My sample code processes just one signal, `inverse_G`.